# Retrieve elements from a list

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I am inserting items in a list and using heapq for the storing the same. Below is my code.. I need to sort the list based on the first column values (ut) and get the top 10 items on my gui. When I try to retrieve data from my list (i.e self.top10ele) using the 'for loop' below I only get 1 row at a time. Also, I am unnable to delete the previous data.. Can someone please guide me what/where I am going wrong?

```
class MyAppl:
    def __init__(self):
            # hastable, lists, tablesize defined 
            self.dir_list = []
            self.dir_list = os.getpids()
            for number in self.dir_list:
                    self.proc_path = /proc/somepath;
                    self.f = open(self.proc_path,'r').read()
                    self.ut = self.f.split()[13]
                    self.st = self.f.split()[12]                 
                    item = Proc_struct.Proc_s(ut,st)
            self.insert(item)

#Hashing here 

def heap(self):
            heap = []
            for i in range(self.tableSize):
                    for j in range(len(self.hashTable[i])):
            heapq.heappush(heap,(self.hashTable[i][j].ut,self.hashTable[i][j].st))
            self.top10ele = (heapq.nlargest(15,heap))

            #for i in range(self.tableSize):
                for k in self.top10ele:
                      self.text.insert(INSERT,k[0],'val')
                      self.text.insert(END, "\t\t")
                      self.text.insert(INSERT,k[1],'val')
                      self.text.insert(END,"\t\t\t")
                      self.text.insert(INSERT,k[2],'val')
                      self.text.insert(END,"\t")
                      self.text.insert(END,"\n")
```

Comment: Is the (lack of) indentation in the nested `for` loops  in `heap()` intentional?

Comment: There are 4 for loops

Comment: ut and st are never defined

Comment: Please excuse the Indentation. This is just the main part of my code, ut, st and heap and lists are all defined. What I would like to know is when i generate sorted data from heap and fetch them in for loop, i am only getting 2 rows instead of 15 (the heap has 15 which i am storing in the list). Also, I want the previous data to be deleted when I fetch new ones.. which is not happening in my code.. Thanks for all the inputs!

Comment: If you want help debugging your code you need to show us real code. Try reproducing the same problem with just 3 or 4 lines of code. It's not clear what you're asking, and the extra code is getting in the way. Read about [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PeterWood: I want to retrieve all the elements in the list. Say, there are 20 rows in a list and each row has 5 columns, I want the output to be just that way - 5 columns, 20 rows displayed under their respective labels on my GUI. Right now, It doesn't fetch and display all the data. This is my problem.. I do not know how to reproduce the problem in such short code.. I am a novice and still learning.. My problem in the above code is, it is not retrieving all the data in the list. So simply put, how to retrieve all the rows with their columns together from a list. I hope this helps..

Comment: `/proc/somepath;` is not valid

Comment: What is `text`? What is `INSERT`? What is `END`?

Comment: I need to pull data from various files, for instance, pid from here: /proc/stat or username from here: /proc/[pid]/environ. I am creating a text box widget and trying to populate the pid and username in each column. INSERT is inserting into my text box. END is tab space/newline in the end of the row. I have defined these in my code. It does fetch the data.. the problem is it isn't fetching all the data.. I have 15 rows with 2 columns in my list (which is self.top10ele in my case) i only displays 2 rows each time. I want to display all the data that's inside my list on to the text box..

Comment: `self.insert(item)` happens after the loop so it will only insert one value (the last item). If you want it to happen for every process id, you need to move it into the loop.